# why am i getting NZEC error in the below code?

Tags: java

This is my code,for which i'am getting NZEC error.Where have i gone wrong?
I tried both throws and try catch ways to solve this but i couldn't.

```
package HaHa;

import java.io.*;

class HaHa {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            int t,k,i,y,n;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String m[]=new String[t];
            for(i=0;i<t;i++) {
                m[i]=br.readLine();
            }
            for(y=0;y<t;y++) {
                char[] num = new char[m[y].length()];
                num=m[y].toCharArray();
                n=m[y].length();
                int mid=n/2;
                int left=mid-1;
                for(k=0;k<=left;) {
                    System.out.print(num[k]);
                    k=k+2;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me why i'am getting this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NZEC in Java Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997539/getting-nzec-in-java-code)

Comment: NO.I have seen those questions.They are not addressing to my question.